# CSS pseudo class :focus after button click

Tags: html, css

I was working with some basic CSS animation for `button`.The problem is the `:focus` pseudo class even works when we press tab on keyboard. So I want that `:focus` should only works when I click on the button i.e only when active.

Here is the code:

```css
button {
  background: #c33;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

button:after {
  content: 'RENT ME';
  display: block;
}

button:active,
button:focus {
  background: green;
}

button:active:after,
button:focus:after {
  display: block;
  animation: shake 1s linear, revert 2s 1s;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes shake {
  from {
    content: "O";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    content: "O";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes revert {
  0% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: -60px
  }
  50% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
```

In the above code the button changes to `green` on press of tab which I want to avoid.Is there a pure CSS solution to it.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/xuuyjgsz/)

Comment: Remove properties for :focus in your css?

Comment: I want to keep :focus only after :active. If I remove :focus then I have to keep on pressing the button for animation to work.

Comment: I don't follow. What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to keep the focus only after the button is active i.e it is clicked.I dont want to loose the focus.If I only use :active the focus will remain only till the button is clicked.

Comment: Made your animation little smoother http://codepen.io/eirenaios/pen/bWgoae ;)

Comment: @eirenaios Thanks for the animation suggestion. The example code is just a sample animation, not what I am using.

Comment: @shubhamagrawal you could probably achieve what you want with just CSS by using checkboxes and some common CSS hacks (e.g. https://codepen.io/miroot/pen/HnsmI). Would you be interested in a such a solution?

Answer (score 7):

use `tabIndex="-1"` on button if you don't want the button to be focusable when pressing tab

```
<button tabIndex="-1"></button>
```

Comment: this would render the button inaccessible to people who need to use a keyboard to access web interfaces. purposefully breaking accessibility should really be avoided...

Answer (score 4):

If a button is active, then it will always be focused at the same time.

So just provide an `:active` rule and provide no `:focus` rule at all.

Comment: The problem is if I use just :focus and no :active I have to consistently press the button for the animation to work.

Comment: @shubhamagrawal — Well yes. "Active" means "*While* being clicked on".  That's what you asked for. (If you want a click to trigger an animation, then add a class using a JavaScript event handler).

Comment: Yes that is the problem that I cant use Javascript to do it.It has to be pure CSS only.

Comment: CSS is not designed to do that job.

Comment: Is there a way for :focus to work only after :active.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: I think you can not do with css. JavaScript should be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get an accessible, or production-worthy solution to this without the use of JavaScript.

If we're to take the purpose of the animation at face value, you're simulating a function that adds an item to a shopping cart.  If that's true, you would only want to load the 'added to card' portion of the animation after the item was actually added. By itself, CSS can't know if that's actually true or not, so you'll never get a working solution with CSS alone.

This is unfortunately not the answer you're looking for, as it involves JavaScript, but it is the solution you're looking to achieve.

```js
var myBtn = document.getElementById('rent_me');

myBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

  if ( myBtn.getAttribute('aria-pressed') === 'false') {
    myBtn.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'true');
    myBtn.classList.add('loading');
    myBtn.querySelector('.init-text').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');

    /*
      This is to simulate the function of actually
      adding this 'item' to the shopping cart.
      Wouldn't be used outside of this example
    */

    setTimeout( function () {
      myBtn.classList.remove('loading');
      myBtn.querySelector('.added-text').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false')
    }, 2000);
  }
  else {
    myBtn.classList.remove('loading');
    myBtn.setAttribute('aria-pressed', 'false');
    myBtn.querySelector('.init-text').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
    myBtn.querySelector('.added-text').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true')
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* setup the button styling */
button {
  background: #c33;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

/* the text inside the button is placed within spans that get pushed in/out the bounding of the button with text-indent and overflow hidden */
button span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition:
    text-indent .2s ease-in-out;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* start with rent me text in view */
.init-text {
  text-indent: 0%;
}

/* added to cart text pushed off to the right */
.added-text {
  text-indent: 200%;
}

/* buttons need a focus state so keyboard users know they've 'focused it'
button:focus {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

/* when the button has been activated, JS will set the aria-pressed value to true, changing the background color of the button */
button[aria-pressed="true"] {
  background: green;
}

/* if the button has been pressed, get the 'rent me' text out of view */
button[aria-pressed="true"] .init-text {
  text-indent: -200%;
}

/* once the button is no longer in the loading phase, bring the 'added to cart' text into view */
button[aria-pressed="true"]:not(.loading) .added-text {
  text-indent: 0%;
}

/* when the button is loading, show a spinner */
.loading:before {
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: rotate 1s infinite;
  position: absolute;
  content: "\21BB";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  speak: none;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
}


/* animation for the spinner */
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="rent_me" aria-pressed="false" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
  <span class="init-text">
    Rent Me
  </span>
  <span class="added-text">
    Added to Cart
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Awesome work dude. Just a little lengthy but it's pitch perfect.

Comment: thanks @YashYadav, and yeh... i have issues with being brief when I feel like there's a lot of context to explain :)

Comment: ya dude. It was surely worth it. :)

Comment: @scottohara great explaination but that is just a sample animation. I dont want a solution based on a single animation.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the selection of your buttons using the tab key at the start, you can try to avoid the use of the `button` element and instead replicate the same behaviour using a `div` with a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute.

Use `tabindex = "-1"` specifically to avoid the switch via the tabs key.

Refer code :

```css
div {
  background: #c33;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  z-index: 10;
  outline: 0;
}

div:first-child {
  margin-left: 1px;
}

div:after {
  content: 'RENT ME';
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}

div:focus {
  background: green;
}

div:focus:after {
  display: block;
  animation: shake 1s linear, revert 2s 1s;
  -webkit-animation: shake 1s linear, revert 2s 1s;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes shake {
  from {
    content: "O";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    content: "O";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes revert {
  0% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: -60px
  }
  50% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1"></div>
<div tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Comment: @nascheez the problem is once the div looses focus the animation doesn't work the next time I click the particular div and even I don't the focus on press of tab

Comment: @shubhamagrawal check the modified code, the animation works now at all times and the tab switch is disabled.

Comment: @nashcheez clicking tab stops the animation which is not what the person wants.

Comment: @YashYadav When you click the tab button, the focus is removed from the button and the animation will stop nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

**MY ANSWER IS DIFFERENT FROM OTHERS.**

```js
$("button").focus(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) { //tab pressed
      event.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
  })
});

$("button").blur(function() {
  $("this").unbind();
});
```

```css
button {
  background: #c33;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

button:after {
  content: 'RENT ME';
  display: block;
}

button:active,
button:focus {
  background: green;
}

button:active:after,
button:focus:after {
  display: block;
  animation: shake 1s linear, revert 2s 1s;
  position: relative;
}

body[data-whatinput="keyboard"] button:focus {
  background: red;
}

@keyframes shake {
  from {
    content: "O";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    content: "O";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes revert {
  0% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: -60px
  }
  50% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/what-input/4.1.1/what-input.min.js"></script>
<button tabindex="-1"></button>
<button tabindex="-1"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set green background temporary. Is it what you want?

```css
button {
  background: #c33;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

button:after {
  content: 'RENT ME';
  display: block;
}

button:active,
button:focus {
    animation: green-bg 4s step-start;
}

button:active:after,
button:focus:after {
  display: block;
  animation: shake 1s linear, revert 2s 1s;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes shake {
  from {
    content: "O";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    content: "O";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes revert {
  0% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: -60px
  }
  50% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    content: 'ADDED TO CART';
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes green-bg {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
```

Comment: Still focus will be there.

Comment: Do you want to reset focus or focus style (background and outline)?

Comment: Reset focus not just style

Comment: The focus is not CSS property. It is necessary to use javascript or user action. Sorry, I don't know how to help you.